# Add space above band in FastReport VCL 5

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have an invoice form that I am working on and I use the page header band as the master data (so that invoice header information appears on each page), and then a Master Band to display the line items of the invoice and finally another master band to display the totals (totals are printed in multiple currencies). I want to space the second master band from the first but I can't see a way to do this.

```
PAGE HEADER (with invoice header)
MASTER DATA BAND (with invoice detail)
<need space here>
MASTER DATA BAND (with invoice totals)
FOOTER
PAGE FOOTER
```

Update:
Here is how the banding is laid out in my report:
[image: Report Bands Layout]

If I put the code suggested in MasterData: Totals OnBeforePrint then this is what I get (I used 40 instead of 5 to make the difference obvious):

[image: Sample with Spacing]

And here is what it looks without the code:

[image: Sample without Spacing]

Here is my code:

```
procedure TotalsOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  if Engine.FreeSpace > Totals.Height + Footer.Height + PageFooter.Height + 40 then
    Engine.CurY := Engine.CurY + 40;  
end;
```

(I flipped the sign in the if statement otherwise it would almost never execute.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @gpi's comment, I added a Child band (named Spacer) to the MasterData:MasterData band (technically a child of TariffRemarks band).  I then added the following script to that Child Band's OnBeforePrint event:

```
procedure SpacerOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  Spacer.Visible := MasterData.Dataset.RecNo = MasterData.Dataset.RecordCount - 1;
end;
```

This works.  I'm not sure why MasterData.Dataset.eof doesn't work but I think that the OnBeforePrint event for the last record fires before the table advances past the last record and sets the eof flag true.  I imagine that Recno is 0 based so MasterData.Dataset.Recno = MasterData.Dataset.Recordcount will also not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add empty child band to masterdata band 
Use in the Child's OnBeforePrint event:

Child1.Visible := not Totals.Dataset.Eof;

Comment: I tried this but it causes a blank line between every MasterData line.  Now that I know you can check the dataset position, I will play around with different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If the detail total band is a fixed height, you can use the band's `OnBeforePrint` (script). I've used the value `5` - set it to whatever spacing you want before then band prints:

```
procedure MasterDataTotalBandBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  // See if there's room for the band between the bottom of the last
  // band (MasterDataDetail) and the footer and page footer.

  if Engine.FreeSpace > MasterDataTotalBand.Height + FooterBand1.Height +
                        PageFooter1.Height + 5 then
    Engine.CurY := Engine.CurY + 5;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do quite what I want because while it puts a space before the totals start printing, it also puts a space between each total line.

Comment: @Caynadian: Um, no. It only affects the positioning of the band itself, unless you're adding the value in the wrong place. The event is only called immediately before the band prints, and it's only applied just before each time the band is printed. It moves the band itself down <x> units, but the total lines stay exactly where they are placed on the band.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working then.  I edited my post to show you my band layout and what is happening along with the code I am using.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?